# MySQL count distinct and show its label

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a sample table called `tblapplicants`

and there is `referral` column on that table. Where all records contains different referral values with duplicated referral values like this

```
ID | referral 
 1 | Internet
 2 | Internet
 3 | News
 4 | News
 5 | News
```

and I wanna get something like this

```
referral | count
Internet | 2 
News     | 3
```

to select referral column and count distinctly all the records and declare `count` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use **count** and **group by** in sql

```
SELECT
  referral
  , count(referral) as count 
FROM
  tblapplicants 
GROUP BY
  referral;
```